# Remove Blank option tag from select list

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello could you please tell me how to remove blank option tag form my select list.
on safari style sheet hack not working. can we do this on j-query.

Comment: what do you mean by blank option? blank by value or blank by text?

Comment: blank value and blank text

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
$('select option')
    .filter(function() {
        return !this.value || $.trim(this.value).length == 0 || $.trim(this.text).length == 0;
    })
   .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value=" ">2014 - January</option>
<option value="2">2014 - February</option>
<option value="3"></option>
<option value="4">2014 - April</option>
<option value="5">2014 - May</option>
<option value="6">2014 - June</option>
<option value="7">2014 - July</option>
<option value="8">2014 - August</option>
<option value="">2014 - September</option>
<option value="10">2014 - October</option>
<option value="11">2014 - November</option>
<option value="">2014 - December</option>
</select>
```

```
$('select option')
.filter(function() {
    return !this.value || $.trim(this.value).length == 0 || $.trim(this.text).length == 0;
})
.remove();
```

use above code with jQuery. It will remove options with blank values and texts.

Answer (score 10):

If you are targeting only latest browser then you can use `:empty` css3 property.

```
 option:empty
{
  display:none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/r43vev8z/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this : remove all options for which text and val both are blank using `filter`.

**NOTE** - you can modify the condition if you want either text or value blank, then put `||` instead of `&&`

```
$(function(){
    $('select option').filter(function(){
        return ($(this).val().trim()=="" && $(this).text().trim()=="");
    }).remove();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7d0cfL3w/14/)**